# Mount a shared volume to Kubernetes cluster so that all users can access same storage and share files

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, jupyterhub

I am following [Zero to JupyterHub with Kubernetes](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create a jupyterHub environment for my team to use.

Using Google Kubernetes Engine and every user gets his/her own storage and files are stored - this setup works fine.

I am having trouble as how should I create a volume or shared database so that everyone in team can see each other's notebooks, share file's and data.

To explain more, in desired setup - when a user signs in and goes to his/her jupyter image - every user sees the same folder "shared" and one can create individual folders for themselves inside that folder but are able to reuse code that someone else has already written.

I looked into NFS with Firestore but that seems very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes) gcePersistenceDisk do not support multiple read and write.
There is alternative solution for the problem. [Rook](https://rook.io/) is a storage backend various storage provisioner available through it. One of them is Ceph which has shared filesystem solution on kubernetes.